# Action Error does not display when using a reload function

Tags: java, jsp

I have set in Action java file that addActionError() is called when there is error. But Now in my JSP class, I have a code that will reload the page when the user click the "submit" button.

My problem now is, the page will reload and not showing the error message. I have used

```
 <s:if test="hasActionErrors()"> 
 <s:actionerror/>
 </s:if>
```

but it will still skip the error and just refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your JavaScript function like this in JSTL:-

```
<s:if test="${hasActionErrors()}"> 
<!--Do your operation here..-->
</s:if>
```